# flash video fallback for IE7 and IE8 doesn't work

Tags: html, video, fallback

I've been looking and trying to find an appropriate video fallback for IE7 and 8. I haven't been able to find one so far. the cleanest code (which I would like to use) is pasted below. it comes from video for everybody.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/XHTML1/DTD/XHTML1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XHTML" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/HTML; charset=utf-8" />
<title>video</title>
</head>
<body>

<video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
    <source src="changePassword.MP4"  type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="changePassword.OGG"  type="video/ogg" />
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer.SWF">
        <param name="movie" value="flowplayer.SWF" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
<p> <strong>Download Video:</strong>
    Closed Format:  <a href="changePassword.MP4">"MP4"</a>
    Open Format:    <a href="changePassword.OGG">"Ogg"</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

does anyone see mistakes or possible improvements? thanks!
thijs

Comment: Have you considered using an out-of-the-box solution like http://jplayer.org or http://videojs.com/?

Comment: thank you for the response. I am not able to work with javascript since I can only embed the video-element into a java (vaadin) program. where I paste the html-code in video.setAltText(String)
    video.setHtmlContentAllowed(true);
    video.setAltText("");

Answer (score 1):

1. First thing make sure you have used correct video path file.
2. If that's not a problem then in video for everybody website they mentioned to include JW player or any other video player as a video fallback. In their [demo page](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test_yt.html) they have embed to YouTube video. Make sure you included the video player.

> Replace "**FLASH**.SWF" with the path to the Flash video player you are using. I use JW Player (download and place ‘player.swf’ in the right place), but this could be any Flash resource including YouTube. Sample code for using YouTube can be seen on the Video for Everybody YouTube Test Page